# Aligning title and y axis labels

Tags: reporting-services

I've got two charts on top of each other, and I'm looking to align the title and y axis as per screenshot. The title's I've done as a separate textbox as I wasn't happy with the rendering when using the chart title label as the output would look slightly different compared to the text in my table with the same font style but happy to change it back to a chart title label provided I can align everything.

No matter how I shift the alignment of the charts, I can't get the y-axis to match. And even if I do, it won't align depend on what the Y-axis label values are. Is there anyway this can be done in SSRS?

[image]

Comment: How do you align the two charts to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (I just found out!), at least it worked for my simple example.

I took an existing test report with a chart in it, duplicated the chart and then set the Y-Axis values for the second one to be 1000 times higher, in order to force the condition you are seeing.

In the design, both charts are aligned but when the chart is rendered, the Y-Axis values are offsetting the chart's Left vertical axis

[image]

I then clicked the 'Chart Area' (see the dotted rectangle in the image) - this is the inner part of the chart...

I then edited the properties for `CustomInnerPlotPosition` and `CustomPosition`, setting both to `Enabled` and then set some values for the `Left` property.  The values themselves I just guessed.

I repeated this for **both** charts making sure the left values were the same in each.

You may not have to change all these properties, so you could experiment, but this did seem to work so I left it.

[image]

Here's the final output.

[image]